# find a word in the sentences and replace whole sentence with a number

Tags: python

I'm a beginner.
I have 757 rows with a different statement. I would like to write a command to find the statement with "e-bike" and replace it with the number 1:
**1st statement**: "a conflict between cyclists and pedestrians, a conflict between two cyclists, a conflict between e-biker and a cyclist"
***2nd statement:*** "a conflict relating to a dog(s), a conflict between cyclists and pedestrians, a conflict between an e-biker and a pedestrian, a conflict between e-biker and a cyclist"
If I want to replace one by one I have to write the 757 command.

Thanks

Elham

Comment: Make sure you ask a clear question.
Do you want to replace the word "e-bike" in all sentences with the word "1", or do you want to replace the full sentence?
Also, are your "757" rows a list, or another type? Try to provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace('<old_string>', '<new_string>')` while iterating through your rows.

```
def replace_rows(rows)
    for i in range(len(rows)):
        rows[i] = rows[i].replace('e-bike', '1')

    return rows
```

Or even with list comprehension:

```
def replace_rows(rows):
    return [i.replace('e-bike', '1') for i in rows]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like, assuming you have a list of sentences `sentences_list` :

```py
results = []

for sentence in sentences_list:
    results.append(sentence.replace("e-bike", "1"))

print(results)
```